# Text Clustering

Tags: python, text, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I ve got 6 txt files filled with questions about the same domain but on differents subjects (each file contains questions of a different subject) and my goal is to cluster those files in order to have a better view of the similarities of the subjects.

I ve already removed the stopwords , applied the stemming process , applied the the TF-IDF  score (i ve got it under the form of a dataframe , it results into a dataframe with 200 words (columns) and  6 subjects (rows)) but I m struggling to know how to apply a kmeans or dbscan as a clustering method and eventually how to evaluate the performance of my clustering method..

thanks for the help in advance..

Comment: What libraries are you using? What have you tried so far?

Comment: About the evaluation, since you already have data divided in subjects, just compare the cluster assignments to the original subjects (as class labels).

Comment: I used get_stop_words from stop_words for the stopwords , re for special characters extraction , FrenchStemmer from nltk.stem.snowball for stemming the documents and a hand made TF-IDF function to get the weights of each words in the differents documents..I apply the k means on a cosine_similarity matrix between the documents (but I am not sure if I should apply the k means on it or on the TF-IDF matrix [wich have each word on the columns and each document on the rows])..

Answer (score 0):

With 6 subjects, clustering is not statistically well founded. both k-means and DBSCAN need much larger sample sizes than that.

Probably the most meaningful approach is using a dendrogram.

Comment: I have calculated a cosine_similarity matrix of each document to others , would it be a best fit if I apply the dendogram on it?